# Odd rpcbind connection

Tags: linux, networking, centos, security, rpcbind

I ran rpcbind on my Centos 8 server and I noted an odd server:

rpcbind      1038     rpc   13u  IPv4 46028565      0t0  TCP CentOS-82-64-minimal:sunrpc->ilijavujovic.tempurl.host:61000 (ESTABLISHED)

Looks very dubious. Any idea how this might have occurred or how to avoid it?

Comment: An IP address would definitely help here. Where is this connection actually going?

Comment: Looks definitely dubious (If I just put the name in a web browser it actually connects and I get a default WordPress site). But there is no way of knowing what on your system actually connected to it, how or why.

Comment: I got this after searching: https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/178.62.55.214 This is scanning the port I assume? Yet I don't understand why it appears alongisde RPCBIND

Comment: Anyway, just as databases, this service should probably never  be exposed to Internet without proper firewalling.